# What's the difference between それならいい and それならいいんですが

Tags: grammar, meaning

What is the difference between それならいい and それならいいんですが?

I'm guessing that the んですが implies some sort of unsaid reservation or concern.

Answer (score 0):

んです is a colloquial saying of のです. A dictionary says のです indicates predication which emphasizes a reason.

I think this が is used when you hover on saying something definitely. For example, こっちの方が良いと思うが, あなたは悪くないと思うが. http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/34931/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%8C/

So それならいいんですが indicate you hover on saying それならいいんです definitely.

Answer (score -3):

それならいい is like the answer of 'それならいいんですが?', meaning that's is ok/acceptable.

それならいいんですが? is asking if that is ok.

ですが is a word to identify is informing the others.

Hope this may help.